# Number of dependencies not shown in BuildInfo (using uploadSpec)

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, maven-2, artifactory

I use a simple `uploadSpec` to upload the `jar` file(s) generated with `maven package` command but when I look at Artifactory's buildInfo I see the module uploaded but it does not show any dependencies.

I am wondering if it is possible to somehow generate the "Number of dependencies" for each module and upload it along with the buildInfo in Artifactory.

Similar to how it can be done with an Artifactory Maven build instance.

```
def rtMaven = Artifactory.newMavenBuild()
def buildInfo = rtMaven.run pom: 'maven-example/pom.xml', goals: 'clean install'
rtMaven.deployer.deployArtifacts buildInfo
```

Comment: In order to generate the list of dependencies, the jar needs to be built using the build tool (maven in this case). That's why you don't see the list of dependencies when you just upload the jar.